# Contact Logging Problem

Tags: logging

i have turned on contact logging on my civicrm for a while when it suddenly couldn't list the contact summary report and reported a DB Error.  When I turned on the debug, the following trace came about:

```
#0 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(190): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()
#1 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(921): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))
#2 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB.php(985): PEAR_Error->__construct("DB Error: unknown error", -1, 16, (Array:2), "INSERT IGNORE INTO civicrm_temp_civireport_logsummary SELECT entity_log_civir...")
#3 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(575): DB_Error->__construct(-1, 16, (Array:2), "INSERT IGNORE INTO civicrm_temp_civireport_logsummary SELECT entity_log_civir...")
#4 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(223): PEAR->_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), NULL, -1, 16, (Array:2), "INSERT IGNORE INTO civicrm_temp_civireport_logsummary SELECT entity_log_civir...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#5 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1907): PEAR->__call("raiseError", (Array:7))
#6 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(933): DB_common->raiseError(-1, NULL, NULL, "INSERT IGNORE INTO civicrm_temp_civireport_logsummary SELECT entity_log_civir...", "1114 ** The table 'civicrm_temp_civireport_logsummary' is full")
#7 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(403): DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()
#8 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1216): DB_mysqli->simpleQuery("INSERT IGNORE INTO civicrm_temp_civireport_logsummary SELECT entity_log_civir...")
#9 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2415): DB_common->query("INSERT IGNORE INTO civicrm_temp_civireport_logsummary SELECT entity_log_civir...")
#10 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1607): DB_DataObject->_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO civicrm_temp_civireport_logsummary SELECT entity_log_civir...")
#11 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(438): DB_DataObject->query("INSERT IGNORE INTO civicrm_temp_civireport_logsummary SELECT entity_log_civir...")
#12 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1420): CRM_Core_DAO->query("INSERT IGNORE INTO civicrm_temp_civireport_logsummary SELECT entity_log_civir...", TRUE)
#13 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Logging/ReportSummary.php(388): CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery("INSERT IGNORE INTO civicrm_temp_civireport_logsummary SELECT entity_log_civir...")
#14 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Logging/ReportSummary.php(431): CRM_Logging_ReportSummary->buildTemporaryTables()
#15 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Report/Form.php(2815): CRM_Logging_ReportSummary->beginPostProcessCommon()
#16 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Report/Form.php(3472): CRM_Report_Form->beginPostProcess()
#17 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(489): CRM_Report_Form->postProcess()
#18 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Submit.php(74): CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()
#19 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Submit->perform(Object(CRM_Report_Form_Contact_LoggingSummary), "submit")
#20 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Report_Form_Contact_LoggingSummary), "submit")
#21 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(351): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("submit")
#22 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Wrapper.php(113): CRM_Core_Controller->run()
#23 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Report/Page/Instance.php(89): CRM_Utils_Wrapper->run("CRM_Report_Form_Contact_LoggingSummary", NULL, (Array:0))
#24 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(309): CRM_Report_Page_Instance->run((Array:4), NULL)
#25 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:14))
#26 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:4))
#27 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1240): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:4))
#28 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke("")
#29 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters("", (Array:1))
#30 /var/www/html/wp-includes/plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))
#31 /var/www/html/wp-admin/admin.php(224): do_action("toplevel_page_CiviCRM")
#32 {main}

 Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
DB Error: unknown error
Error Details
Return to home page.
```

It seems like "civicrm_temp_civireport_logsummary' is full"  is the issue here but the diskspace is quite abundant on my server.  However, it seems that if I select any value for the report using the Filters, the report generates ok, the error came up only if I do not specify any filters.

Thanks for any advise on what i can do from here.

System Specs: CIVICRM 5.8.2 Wordpress 4.9.9

Comment: are you talking about this https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/report/instance/40 ? or this https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/report/instance/1 ? or something else?

Comment: Hello, this is actually on an instance that i have installed on my own server.

Comment: You describe the report as "the contact summary report" - does an equivalent of the report exist on dmaster?